# How to add threadName to Jmeter HTML report (error section)

Tags: jmeter, report

I am facing an issue when I try to analyze Jmeter HTML report.
I use this command to run and create HTML report

```
jmeter -n -t C:\JMETER_RTB_REQUEST\Framework\Test_Fragment\Test_Fragment_15_02_2018_vol2.jmx -l C:\Users\bs\Desktop\Jmeter_reports\results_geo.csv -e -o C:\Users\bs\Desktop\Jmeter_reports\HTML
```

The problem is that when I am opening the Html file, under error section it not mention on which test (thread group) it failed, so I can not understand what test failed. In the CSV exists thread name column, but not in the HTML error section. Is their any solution?
[[image]][Thread groups from test plan]

[[image: CSV Results]][CSV report thread Name exists(HTML1 is thread name)]

[[image: HTML Reports][HTML report not mentioned thread Name]]

Answer (score 0):

Since JMeter 4.0, you can customize assertion message:

[image: Custom Message assertion]

So you would put custom message assertion including Thread Name calling [__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function.

Comment: Thanks Ubik but this is No solution it. will be OK if someone build framework from scratch, But I have plenty of tests and steps, I can not now change each step manually, Moreover If I want to order by test (thread group)  it can not be done according to this solution, since no column of thread group name . Is their any other solution that you know?